# Excel formula to find largest date in the pool and return corresponding value

Tags: excel

I have research this question on the site and else I still can't find the right answer.

```
Account     Date         Status
115937      4/29/2015   BegunFlow
116448      5/5/2015    EnrollmentRejected
116448      4/9/2015    Rejected
116523      4/24/2015   EnrollmentRejected
120070      4/29/2015   BegunFlow
120070      5/2/2015    BegunFlow
1736792     4/29/2015   Inactive
1736792     5/1/2015    BegunFlow
2755700     4/24/2015   EnrollmentSubmitted
10418622    4/9/2015    CreditFail
25058075    5/5/2015    Active
25058075    4/9/2015    Pending Start
34359030    4/9/2015    Pending Start
34362064    4/9/2015    Pending Start
161020809   4/9/2015    CreditFail
161020809   4/9/2015    CreditFail
161020809   4/10/2015   PreenrollmentCancel
405423048   5/9/2015    CreditFail
405423048   4/9/2015    CreditFail
415096105   4/9/2015    Waiting Termination
651119087   4/9/2015    Active
858051162   4/9/2015    Active
949429029   4/9/2015    Active
949429029   4/10/2015   Rejected
```

this is a data sample of what I have been struggling to do. I want to be able to match account column with the recent date in date column and return corresponding status column.

This is the formula I have tried

```
=VLOOKUP(MAX(IF($A:$A=E1,$B:$B)),$B$1:$C$24,2,0)
```

The problem with this formula is it convert the date to number. I have large rows.

Comment: What is in column E1?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with converting the date to a number. The problem comes from converting the output of an array formula into an input.

It will work if you separate the `MAX/IF` from the `VLOOKUP`. Just get the output of the `MAX` you're looking for into one cell, and then use that cell as the input for the `VLOOKUP`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using an Array formula combined with Match and Index.

Something like: `=INDEX($C:$C,MATCH(MAX(IF($A:$A=$E$1,$B:$B,0)),IF(A:A=$E$1,$B:$B,0),0))`
should work. You need to enter it as an Array formula by pressing Ctrl-Enter to finish editing.

Basically this is creating a filtered date column (`IF($A:$A=$E$1,$B:$B,0)`), picking the maximum, finding the row (`INDEX`) and then using that to look up in Column C (`MATCH`).

Comment: Although I'd strongly recommend not using entire column references within an array formula. That set-up will be forced to calculate over more than two million cells. Unlike e.g. COUNTIF(S)/SUMIF(S), array formulas calculate over all cells passed to them, whether technically beyond the last-used cells in those ranges or not.

Comment: Completely agree and would limit to the size of the range.

Answer (score 0):

*The following is been worked out using the sample data provided.*

If my understanding is correct, what you are looking for is a formula that returns\highlights the following:

```
Account   Date       Status
405423048 05/09/2015 CreditFail
```

However, also noticed that several Accounts shared a common date, therefore in a scenario where the above record is not present then the latest date would be `05/09/2015`, the result for the latest records would be something like this:

```
Account  Date       Status
116448   05/05/2015 EnrollmentRejected
25058075 05/05/2015 Active
```

So what I’m pointing out here is that the result of the Account with the latest Status updated could be a Range\Array with several records

Now, with that clear, we could have at least two kinds of output:

1. Highlight, flag, the resulting records in the Source Data
2. Generate a separate range\array with the resulting records

The formula proposed below will serve both requirements *(please let know if your requirement is indeed something different)*

First, we should add a Field *(called “Latest”)* to the Source Data to reflect the formula’s result, we use column *“D”*, enter the following formula for every record in this field *(this is not a FormulaArray)*:

```
=IF(B7=MAX($B:$B),"Latest Record","")
```

Press {F9} (if using manual calculation) then all the records with most recent update will be *“flagged”* as `Latest Records` in your Source Data under the field *Latest*

This, up here, satisfies the Output 1.

If the requirement is Output 2 then:
Filter the Source Data using Field "Latest” with the value "Latest Record", 
select the VisibleCell within the Source Data then paste the range of VisibleCells to your target destination.

However, as this seems to be a repetitive task, I suggest to create a Macro to do it.